# Can I override the extension directory from htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, heroku

Not sure what it's referred to here wether it's the plugin directory or what, but basicly I'm hosting a site on heroku, it has the standard apache with all the overrides already enabled, what I basically want to ask is, I want to install the mongodb extension but I have no direct access to the php.ini, can it be done from htaccess and how do I go about doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, turns out if you mount mongodb to composer and copy the composer.json and lock files to your heroku app, Heroku will automatically mount mongodb to the php library.